# How do I seperate each list item to minus that item, python

Tags: python

How am I meant to minus each item off a list, all items are an integer, this is my code:

```
def final():
    w = 0
    for def1 in range(0,x):
        with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
            o = (var1 / x) - def1[w]
            print(o, file = f)
        w = w + 1
```

x defines the amount of items in the list, it is determined earlier in my code and is a global variable, do not worry why the var1 is being divided, in this instance I used w as the part which determines which item will be chosen from the list. def1 is just the name of the list. Would be greatly appreciated if you guys can help out. :)

Comment: `def1` is an integer for each possible value in `range(x)`. It isn't a list.

Answer (score 0):

`def1` is not the list, but an element of the list. Your code should look like this:

```
def final():
    for def1 in range(0,x):
        with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
            o = (var1 / x) - def1
            print(o, file = f)
```